# How do I update a column with parameterized queries, in sqlite3 using C?

Tags: c, sqlite

I have one row that is initialized to 0. I want to update the value of this row every an action is performed.

```
char *text="Hello" // Hello is the name of the field, which has one row    
char *sql = "UPDATE Candidate SET ?=?+1;";


rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);

if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {  
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text( res, 1,text,-1,0);
    rc = sqlite3_bind_text( res, 2,text,-1,0);
}
```

How do I update a column with parameterized queries?

Comment: You cannot bind database schema identifiers (table or column names) to SQL parameters.

Comment: (Disclaimer: I'm inexperienced in C.) Parameterised queries tend to be designed for _values_, to filter out strings containing SQL injection. I'm guessing some string-replace function or `sprintf` will work for columns.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind table or column names to SQL parameter values. From the SQLite [documentation](https://sqlite.org/cintro.html#binding_parameters_and_reusing_prepared_statements)

> #### 6. Binding Parameters and Reusing Prepared Statements
>
> **. . .**
>
> SQLite allows a parameter wherever a string literal, numeric constant, or NULL is allowed. **(Parameters may not be used for column or table names.)** A parameter takes one of the following forms:
>
> • ?
> • ?NNN
> • :AAA
> • $AAA
> • @AAA
>
> In the examples above, NNN is an integer value and AAA is an identifier. A parameter initially has a value of NULL. Prior to calling sqlite3_step() for the first time or immediately after sqlite3_reset(), the application can invoke the sqlite3_bind() interfaces to attach values to the parameters. Each call to sqlite3_bind() overrides prior bindings on the same parameter.
>
> An application is allowed to prepare multiple SQL statements in advance and evaluate them as needed. There is no arbitrary limit to the number of outstanding prepared statements. Some applications call sqlite3_prepare() multiple times at start-up to create all of the prepared statements they will ever need. Other applications keep a cache of the most recently used prepared statements and then reuse prepared statements out of the cache when available. Another approach is to only reuse prepared statements when they are inside of a loop.

If you want to use a variable column name in this situation, you will have to construct the query string dynamically at run-time, which is outside the scope of this question; something like this may work, but it would be worth the time to write a string substitution function if you intend to do this frequently:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[256];
    char *field = "Hello";
    
    strcpy(buffer, "UPDATE Candidate SET ");
    strcat(buffer, field);
    strcat(buffer, " = ");
    strcat(buffer, field);
    strcat(buffer, " + 1;");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `snprintf()` would be better than all those `strcat()`s. Or  even better, [sqlite3_mprintf()](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) to not have length limits and to take advantage of its `%w` format for escaping idenitifer names.... `char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE \"%w\" SET \"%w\" = \"%w\" + 1", table_name, column_name, column_name);`

Comment: That's true, but this code is not intended to solve the string substitution, but only to illustrate it as separate from the query parameter mechanism.